# XML Authoring with MS Word

Tags: xml, interop, ms-word

I was planing to create XML documents based on a custom XSD xcheme. MS Word was a good tool for that I could use a "familiar" tool to create some documents and mark-ups. However, I learned that [Custom XML support was dropped](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978951). MS Word can edit Custom XML but it strips Custom XML tags before saving.

I wonder if I can programatically interop with MS Word and export or recover the XML source. I will be glad if you could point me somewhere. Or is there any other efficient way to do this?

**not 1:** I live outside of US, that I believe I don't have any legal issues with that.

**not 2:** I tried oxygen XML author, it is fine, but not as user-friendly as MS Word.